# Lot's of blank spaces getting into database.... (PHP, Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, null

Good day, 
First off I'm an I.T starting to get into coding, so please be gentle ^^.

So currently I'm building a script where it takes input (Nexmo) and sends it to my database.

Sadly LOTS of blank spaces seem to be filling up my database. For some reason I can't seem to be able to filter out these nulls?

Would anyone be willing to help? 
Thanks!
Heres the code

```
require('db.php');
if (!$connect) {
    die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO `INCOMING` (`TO`, `TEXT` , `FROM`, `MESSAGEID`) VALUES ('$_GET[to]','$_GET[text]' ,'$_GET[msisdn]' , '$_GET[messageId]')";
if (!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
else  {

    echo "TO";
}


mysql_close();
```

Comment: `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`?

Comment: You can use !empty() check before inserting into DB and insert only if those variables are present

Comment: I admit I came here to see what *black spaces* stood for. :) Anyway you should avoid using `mysql_` functions and choose from `mysqli` or `PDO`. `mysql_` is deprecated and will be swallowed by a black hole once PHP7 stable is out.

Comment: Would be nice to know why you have these nulls at all. Are they supposed to be there ? Is it allowed that one of the $_GET is empty ? and do you wanna make a insert if not all $_GET's are set ?

Comment: @JitendraPurohit VARCHAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow *and* to programming!

First of all, I get that you're learning but I'm going to be hard on you to help you. You've got a bad habit from a book or tutorial and I'm not going to let you learn it.

SQL Injection is the [#1 vulnerability on OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project). By inserting data directly from the request (i.e., `$_GET`) into a SQL query, you are exposing this vulnerability. At the very minimum, escape the data first before integrating with the query

```
$to = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['to']);
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['text']);
$msisdn = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['msisdn']);
$messageId = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['messageId']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `INCOMING` (`TO`, `TEXT` , `FROM`, `MESSAGEID`) VALUES ('$to','$text' ,'$msisdn' , '$messageId')";
```

I know it looks like more work but *good programming is not about saving yourself keystrokes.* That being said, you're much better off switching to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) and using parameterized queries. Besides, the `mysql_*` family of functions [are deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Now - on to your actual problem. All incoming data needs to be validated and oftentimes filtered to match the business rules of your application.  For example, if you want to require that all of these fields have at least one non-whitespace character, you'll need to enforce that. Building off the snippet from above:

```
function filterInput($value)
{
    // Trim all leading/trailing whitespace and newlines
    return preg_replace('/^[\s\r\n]+|[\s\r\n]+$/', $value);
}

function validateInput($value)
{
    if (NULL === $value || '' === $value) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

// Filter input per your business rules
$to = filterInput($_GET['to']);
$text = filterInput($_GET['text']);
$msisdn = filterInput($_GET['msisdn']);
$messageId = filterInput($_GET['messageId']);

// Now verify they all have real values
if (validateInput($to) && validateInput($text) && validateInput($msisdn) && validateInput($messageId)) {
    // Now escape for SQL
    $to = mysql_real_escape_string($to);
    $text = mysql_real_escape_string($text);
    $msisdn = mysql_real_escape_string($msisdn);
    $messageId = mysql_real_escape_string($messageId);

    // Proceed with INSERT
}
```

And yet again, I'm sure you're thinking "holy cow that looks like a lot of work" because I took one line of your code and turned it into 20, but that's part of the deal with programming. It's also why people spend lots and lots of time writing libraries and frameworks to abstract-away a lot of this type of "grunt work" code.

Happy coding!

Comment: Peter, I would like to thank you alot for helping me with this problem and actually showing me my bad habits!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you don't send empty spaces to the database, you could replace

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `INCOMING` (`TO`, `TEXT` , `FROM`, `MESSAGEID`) 
   VALUES ('$_GET[to]','$_GET[text]' ,'$_GET[msisdn]' , '$_GET[messageId]')";
```

with

```
if( !empty($_GET['to']) and !empty($_GET['text']) and !empty($_GET['msisdn']) and !empty($_GET['messageId']) ) {
  $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO `INCOMING` (`TO`, `TEXT` , `FROM`, `MESSAGEID`) 
    VALUES ('%s','%s' ,'%s' , '%s')", 
    trim($_GET['to']), trim($_GET['text']), 
    trim($_GET['msisdn']), trim($_GET['messageId']));
}
```

This way you'll have leading and trailing spaces, new-lines and other not-printable characters removed before the insert **and** the insert will only be executed if you have all the information.

Aside from that, the only thing to make sure is that your columns are not of type `CHAR`, as that would cause the empty spaces regarding of what you send from your code.

I'd also advise against sending information from the browser (GET) straight to the database as it could cause some serious security issues.